# Apache 2.4 multiple chained elseif arguments cause an error

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy the Apache configs:

```
Syntax error on line 46 of /data/apache2/conf/mydomain.conf:
Multiple <ElseIf> arguments not supported.
```

Here is my config

```
<If "%{REQUEST_METHOD} == 'POST'">
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store"
Header set Edge-Control "no-store"
</If>

<ElseIf  "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^(/api/bin/getData\.json)#">
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=900"
Header set Edge-Control  "!no-store, public, max-age=900"
</ElseIf>

<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/api#" && "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#(.*)form.token(.*)#">
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=0"
Header set Edge-Control  "!no-store, public, max-age=300"
</ElseIf>

# never cache requests with parameters
<ElseIf  "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ m#^..*#">
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache"
Header set Edge-Control  "no-store"
</ElseIf> 

<Else>
# do somethign else
</Else>
```

It barks on the first occurence of ElseIf

But the docs for Apache say:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#elseif

*The  applies the enclosed directives if and only if both the given condition evaluates to true and the most recent  or  section in the same scope has not been applied.*

This means it should be possible to have multiple chained ElseIf statements in the config, but still it throws an error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the problem were wrong quotes splitting the expression in

```
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/api#" && "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#(.*)form.token(.*)#">
```

The logical AND is not part of the expression anymore. The error message Apache returns is misleading.

Comment: It would be better if your example showed the solution instead of re-printing the mistake ;) Probably why someone came along later and re-answered it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that each `If` can only handle one "expression", indicated by the double quotes.

So instead of

```
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/api#" && "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#(.*)form.token(.*)#">
```

it would need to be

```
<ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/api# && %{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#(.*)form.token(.*)#">
```

I fully agree that the error is very misleading.